# How do you change Controllers folder in WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Instead of the usual "/Controllers" folder, I want to put my WebApi actions in a "/SomeRootFolder/SubFolder/Controllers" location.

How do I change the config for this?

Right now my WebApiConfig says (by default):

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Is `/SomeRootFolder/SubFolder` the same for all controllers? If not, how many combinations are there? Can one controller only be in one subfolder? Is it about the location in the project or about the route that a client uses to access a controller?

Comment: All controllers are in the same folder. All I have done is moved the folder up 2 levels. The URL needs to be the same : mywebsite.com/mycontroller/myaction/myid.  So I dont want the folder to be reflected in the url, I just need for .net to know where to look

Comment: If you move a controller to another folder, do you get an error? I think Web API should find the controller no matter where in the project it is located.